# How to convert short user name into actual Windows user name

Tags: windows, user-accounts

The `startname` field of a `Win32_Service` WMI query reports "LocalSystem" instead of "NT AUTHORITY\System".  Ordinarily this wouldn't be a problem, but the file ACLs I need to create will only accept the full name - not the short name.

Is there a way to convert LocalSystem into NT AUTHORITY\System?

Comment: The service control manager supports "LocalSystem", "LocalService", and "NetworkService" as non-localized names for the standard service accounts. "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" is a localized name. You can just special-case these names to get the SID via `CreateWellKnownSid`.

Comment: Odd how it appears to do this for LocalSystem only.  For example, I haven't seen "NetworkService" - I've only seen "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service".

Comment: A service configuration uses "LocalSystem" or ".\LocalSystem"  for the SYSTEM account, but the SCM requires "NT AUTHORITY" for "LocalService" and "NetworkService". Try the following command to list them all: `wmic PATH Win32_Service WHERE "StartName LIKE '%system' OR StartName LIKE '%service'" GET Name,StartName`.